# Trusted App for install Chrooted Linux Distro

Tags: android, linux

I need a working app **that I can trust (because of the root privileges normally these apps need)** for install debian or another distro on my phone.

Requirements:

- **free and open source**
- **trust of the open source community, code reviewed a lot also by some experienced users on security matters**
- unneeded privileges must be avoided (eg: some seemingly requires identity for unknown reasons, if the developers wants to track the number of active devices they should generate a random cookie ad use that, i don't want my imei and personal data to travel outside)
- autostart with android (i would like have it always active, possibily without destroy my battery)
- file container installation at least ( want to preserve the original android environment as much as possible)
- custom mounts would be a nice feature (at least the storages internal and sdcard)
- frequently updated, and as more options, the better
- if on F-Droid is even better

I read on https://wiki.debian.org/ChrootOnAndroid that various options and app exists with also the capability of doing everything manually with terminal but i would like more using a manager app.

Comment: There's Linux Deploy but I had no time for install it and check settings, read a bit of the code or anything. Seems to be hosted on sourceforge but other things are referred to external websites. Someone can give suggestions about it ?